# Application of the `IntegrateChangeVariables` if one needs to transform an unknown integrand

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The function `IntegrateChangeVariables` is very useful if one has an explicit function under the integral.
However, I faced a need to transform an integral containing an unknown function. The transformation involves both the function and the variables.

**My question**: Is there a possibility to do these sorts of things?

I did not find them in the documentation.

To be precise: let us look at the integral:

```
Integrate[D[Z[X, Y],X]^2, {X, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {Y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

where `Z[X,Y]` is an unknown function. Assume that we need to transform both `X`, `Y`, and `Z[X,Y]`.
In the simplest case, let us perform the scaling transformation:
`X==a*x`,  `Y==a*Y` and `Z[X,Y]==A*z[x,y]`.

Of course, I can easily do this "by hand." What I am interested in is learning to make such and more complex kinds of things using `IntegrateChangeVariables`.

**Do you know a way (or workaround) to make that (or more complex transform) using** `IntegrateChangeVariables`**?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do it this way:

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][
  D[Z[X, Y], X]^2,
  {X, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {Y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}],
 {x, y}, {X == a*x, Y == a*y}]
% /. Z -> Function[{X, Y}, A*z[X/a, Y/a]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Right, this is a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a workaround. Here it is:

Since I did not find any specific built-in way for that let us start with regarding the integrand, `D[Z[X, Y], X]^2` as if it is an equation. To achieve this, I will, for a moment, equate it to zero: `D[Z[X, Y], X]^2==0`.

```
eq1 = Inactive[DSolve][D[Z[X, Y], X]^2 == 0, Z, {X, Y}];
```

Further, let us first change variables in this equation

```
expr1 = DSolveChangeVariables[eq1, 
  z, {x, y}, {X == a*x, Y == a*y, Z[X, Y] == A*z[x, y]}]
```

[image]

From this we only need

```
expr1[[1, 1]]
```

[image]

Now, it is possible to finalize the calculation:

```
Assuming[{a > 0, {x, y} \[Element] Reals}, 
 IntegrateChangeVariables[
  Inactive[Integrate][expr1[[1,1]], {X, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {Y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], {x,y}, {X == a*x, Y == a*y}]]
```

[image]

This is what expected. Done.

I will be grateful for other approaches.